# Check if two different generic type list has the same element

Tags: c#

I have two generic lists that aren't from the same type, but their types have  some properties in common property(Date_Debut, Date_Fin, NombreJours). I want to check if these two lists have the same element considering their common properties. any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the easy way or the hard way. The hard way would be to use reflection to pull the properties with the same name and types and compare their values. It's not hard per say, but it's more involved and is more intensive. You could also manually type the comparison using the two classes. It works, but it's not reusable if you think you might have more classes that shares those properties.

Or you can share an interface.

```
public interface ISharedProperty
{
    DateTime Date_Debut {get;set;}
    DateTime Date_Fin {get;set;}
    int NombreJours {get;set;}
}
```

Then have an `IEqualityComparer<ISharedProperty>` or an extension method (or both)

```
public class SharedPropertyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ISharedProperty>
{
    public bool Equals(ISharedProperty x, ISharedProperty y)
    {
        // Add some logic to check for x and y null value
        return x.Date_Debut == y.Date_Debut &&
               x.Date_Fin == y.Date_Fin &&
               x.NombreJours == y.NombreJours;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ISharedProperty x)
    {
        // Left for you to implement
    }
}
```

You can use your equality comparer in some collections or create one to check for equality. You can use an extension method to help you out.

```
public static bool EqualsTo(this ISharedProperty x, ISharedProperty y)
{
    return new SharedPropertyEqualityComparer().Equals(x, y);
}

// And use your extension method. Class1 and Class2 
// implements ISharedProperty here
Class1 one = /* some value */;
Class2 two = /* some value */;

one.EqualsTo(two);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listA = new List<YourType1>();
var listB = new List<YourType2>();

foreach ( var elementA in listA )
{
    if ( listB.Any(elementB => elementA.Date_Debut == elementB.Date_Debut && 
                               elementA.Date_Fin== elementB.Date_Fin && 
                               elementA.NombreJours == elementB.NombreJours ) ) 
    {
        /// elementA and element b is equal
    }
}
```

And if you don't want to put a condition that long, than you can override your classes `Equals` methods. Then just use that `Equals` method for comparing your objects.

Comment: Thanks M Tolga, that check if the entire two list have the same data ?

Comment: Think it like this, it iterates through the list A, for each element of list A it looks into list B, if any element has the same values of those shared properties than the statement is true, and now you are in if clause, otherwise it just looks for the next element in list A. But I must say that @Simon Belanger's answer makes much more sense if you'll do further list operations between these lists.